# AlertViewController within UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I am building a Swift 3 app with the following Storyboard:

[image]

On the left (in green) is a **UIPageViewController** that holds the 2 **NavigationController** as 2 pages. This allows the user to swipe between 2 subparts of the app.

The problem is the following. I'm trying to display an alert in tha black **UIViewController**.

Here is the code to display the alert:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {         
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "World", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { action in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It works but I always get the the below warning:

`Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`

I also tried with `DispatchQueue.main.async` to present the view but I ran into the same warning.

However what I found is, if I set the **NavigationController** (bottom one) as the initial view controller, it works without the warning.

So, does using a **UIPageViewController** mean the pages will be kind of detached ?

What am I missing here ? Do I forgot to link stuff ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following.

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When you are done you can dismiss it.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Ok it worked. So I cannot present views from controllers within pages ? am I forced to use the `rootViewController` every time ?